# Web Essentials, command line utility to bundle script files?

Tags: javascript, bundle, web-essentials

I'd like to start bundling our javascript files.  I've found that it's really easy locally using the web essentials plugin, however I need to set up the build server to generate the bundled .js file.

I'd rather not check this generated file into TFS as it will cause conflicts for our developers, and also since it's generated from the source I feel that the server build should generate it.

Is there a command line utility for doing the script bundling outside of visual studio that could be used as part of a build script? My google-fu is failing to find one.

Many thanks,

Comment: Having the same problem here. Surely of all the people using Web Essentials now, someone has found a way to generate the bundle file from cmd line.

Comment: It's been a while, what did you end up doing about this?  I'm in the same boat.

Comment: @barsh I wrote my own bundler using the Web Essentials schema, just reads the XML, finds the files, and bundles them together.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you wrote it as proper AMD modules, require.js comes with a tool to turn all your files into an optimized bundle.

Comment: Thanks Mike, we're planning to move to AMD in future, but we're not at that stage just now.

Comment: then good news: if each file you wrote represents on object, you can make it an AMD module in a few seconds: `(function() {` at the start, and `if(window.define) { define(function() { return ThisObject; }; } else { window.ThisObject = ThisObject; } }())` at the end, now it slots into any AMD system.